# Aggregated information and projection in Pig Latin

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm trying to apply a maximum aggregate function to a table by grouping on some fields and projecting. Can I refer to other non-grouping fields in the original table in the aggregating projection?

As as example I have a table blah with schema (user_id: long, order_id: long, product_id: long, gender: chararray, size: int), where user_id, order_id and product_id create a composite key but there can be multiple user ids and order ids. To get the maximum size for each order I use

```
result_table = foreach (group blah by (user_id, order_id)) generate
   FLATTEN(group) as (user_id, order_id),
   MAX(blah.size) as max_size;
```

Is there some way I can also add product_id to the creation of result_table so I have a table containing the user_id, order_id, product_id and max_size (max_size would be duplicated over differing product_ids) ?

If I could refer to the product_id specific to each grouped user_id and order_id I can save myself a mapreduce job by not joining back with the original table to access this field. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Pig is well suited for such things, it has bags and that enables it to do things which in SQL require extra joins.

If you do the following:

```
grp = group blah by (user_id, order_id);
describe grp;
```

you will see that there is a bag with the schema identical to the schema of the "blah" (something like group:(user_id:long, order_id: long), blah: {(user_id: long, order_id: long, product_id: long, gender: chararray, size: int)}). That is a very powerful thing as it will allow us to create an output with all of the original rows with group summaries in each row without using inner joins:

```
grp = group blah by (user_id, order_id);
result_table = foreach grp generate 
   FLATTEN(blah.(user_id, order_id, product_id)), -- flatten the bag created by original group
   MAX(blah.size) as max_size;
```

if the same product_id appears multiple times within group of user_id, order_id than there will be duplicates, to avoid it we could use a DISTINCT nested into FOREACH:

```
grp = group blah by (user_id, order_id);
result_table = foreach grp {
    dist = distinct blah.(user_id, order_id, product_id); -- remove duplicates
    generate flatten(dist), MAX(blah.size) as max_size;
}
```

It will be done in a single MapReduce job.

Comment: Thanks Alexei, I'll experiment with this method, it looks like what I needed.

Comment: Question: in the second example where you do the distinct against the three fields of blah can you refer to the original size value such that the distinct occurs based on those three values but the resultant rows still contain size?

Comment: It is already there, dist is a separate bag from blah, distinct did not change the blah, thus MAX(blah.size) returns the result you want.

Comment: Ah, but it would be possible to do: 
grp = group blah by (user_id, order_id);
result_table = foreach grp {
    dist = distinct blah.(user_id, order_id, product_id);
    generate flatten(dist), flatten(blah.size), MAX(blah.size) as max_size;
}

Comment: Be careful of "flatten(dist), flatten(blah.size)" as it will create a Cartesian product between all records in dist bag and in blah bag, you will get blah.size for a blah.product_id which is not equal to dist.product_id. The fundamental problem is which size will you choose in cases when the same values of user_id, order_id, product_id has more than one row with different values of size?